# format python list stored in bucket storage to read it with Bigquery

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a simple list of items:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', etc...]
```

They could belong to a bigger object called product.

I found that the following format work but item are nested under one row.

```
{'product': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']}
```

How can I convert my list to have one item per row in bigquery with a column named `product`?

I'm running my code in python in a cloud function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to have one item per row in BigQuery:

```py
[{'product': 'item1'}, {'product': 'item2'}, {'product': 'item3'}]
```

To transform your list of items to a list of products in Python:

```py
items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
products = []
for item in items:
    product = {'product': item}
    products.append(product)
```